# How to write a function that split each line on the comma character?

Tags: python, split

For example:

```
Myfunction("1,2,3\n4,5,6")
```

The output will be `[["1","2","3"],["4","5","6"]]`

Answer (score 7):

Use a list comprehension:

```
def myfunction(somestring):
    return [line.split(',') for line in somestring.split('\n')]
```

Demo:

```
>>> def myfunction(somestring):
...     return [line.split(',') for line in somestring.split('\n')]
... 
>>> myfunction("1,2,3\n4,5,6")
[['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6']]
```

Alternatively, you can use [`str.splitlines()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines), which works just like `.split()` but will split the data on *any* newline character combination, be that `\r`, `\n` or `\r\n`. It handles the last line a little smarter too.

If this data comes from a file, consider using the right tools though; the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) can handle the intricacies of quoting on comma-separated data much better:

```
import csv

with open('/your/csv/file.csv', 'rb') as inputfile:
    reader = csv.reader(inputfile)
    for row in reader:
        # row is a list of column values
```

The data doesn't *have* to come from a file, `csv` can handle any iterable, including the result of `.splitlines()`:

```
reader = csv.reader(somestring.splitlines())
for row in reader:
    # row is a list of column values
```

Comment: You might want to consider `splitlines` instead of `split('\n')`. (After considering, you may not switch, of course—sometimes you want to keep the `\r` around to make it easier to notice that you're being fed DOS-style text files when you didn't expect them, etc.) Also, I'd use `csv` even if the data don't come from a file—you can feed `csv.reader` a `StringIO`, or even a list of lines (as of… 2.5 or so… it doesn't need a file-like object, just an iterable over lines).

Comment: @abarnert: There, elaborated.

Answer (score 2):

Use a list comprehension with `str.split` and `str.splitlines`:

```
>>> strs = "1,2,3\n4,5,6"
>>> strs.splitlines()
['1,2,3', '4,5,6']
>>> [x.split(',') for x in strs.splitlines()]
[['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6']]
```

help on `str.splitlines`:

```
>>> print str.splitlines.__doc__
S.splitlines(keepends=False) -> list of strings

Return a list of the lines in S, breaking at line boundaries.
Line breaks are not included in the resulting list unless keepends
is given and true.
```

Answer (score 2):

If the input is M lines of length N, here's a generator that takes O(N) space instead of O(M*N):

```
def myfunction(text):
    from StringIO import StringIO
    for line in StringIO(text):
        yield line.rstrip().split(',')
```

It returns an iterator rather than a concrete list in order to reduce memory consumption.  You can use the result in a for loop or similar, and if you really want the output as a list, just pass it to the `list()` constructor.

Comment: You could just use a generator expression instead of writing a function: `(line.rstrip().split(',') for line in StringIO(text))`. I think, at least in simple cases, that genexps are easier to understand for novices: "it's just like a list comprehension, but lazy" makes intuitive sense; "it's like a function, but yields multiple times instead of returning once" is a bit more to get your head around.

Comment: I suppose, but I love functions and wish people wrote more of them.  :)

Comment: Well, you can always write a function that returns the genexp as an iterator—or, if you've got 3.3, `yield from` the genexp. Personally, I love code that's just a sequence of genexps, each one transforming an iterator into another iterator (like slide 1-39 at http://www.dabeaz.com/generators-uk/GeneratorsUK.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing this function to read stuff from a file, then the `csv` module is your friend:

```
import csv

with open('somefile.txt') as f:
   reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
   lines = list(reader)
```

Comment: In fact, even if you _aren't_ reading from a file, just do `f = StringIO.StringIO(foo)` then you can use a `csv.reader(f)`.

Comment: True, but I think for the OP that might have been a bit too much :)

Comment: Well, you can also just use `csv.reader(foo.splitlines())`, but I didn't want to suggest that until finding out when `csv` started accepting any iterable over lines. (2.5 definitely does; I don't think 2.3 does; the docs don't say.) Anyway, the point is that using `csv` has all the same advantages whether the data comes from a file or stdin or a socket or whatever.